# Multiplying Two Compressed Upper Triangular Matrices

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I am terrible at linear algebra and I am having an incredibly hard time building my loops to multiply two compressed matrices without expanding them and including the zeros.

For example,

```
0 1 2 3  * 10 11 12 13
0 4 5 6    0  14 15 16
0 0 7 8    0  0  17 18
0 0 0 9    0  0  0  19
```

is actually just

```
a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
b = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
```

I initially had

```
for(i = 0; i < r1; ++i)
    for(j = 0; j < c2; ++j)
        for(k = 0; k < c1; ++k)
        {
            *(mult(i * cols) + j) += *(a(i * cols) + k) * (b + (k * cols) + j;
        }
```

but this obviously goes out of bounds because it is built as if they are 2D arrays and goes to 16 when the size of each array is only 10 elements.

I have observed that the diagonals are just the products of only the elements on the diagonals, so for example c[4] = a[4] * b[4]. I also understand that for the first row you multiply the same number of terms as there are columns, the second row you multiply that many terms - 1 and so forth.

But beyond that, I am fairly lost on how to construct the actual code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward programming. To multiply two matrices together, the number of columns of the first matrix must be the same as the number of rows of the second.

For example, if A is an M X N matrix and B is an N X P matrix, the multiplication works. The result of the multiplication is an M X P matrix. In your example, the matrices are square and the same size, so the multiplication works.

In any case, you are going to end up with a third matrix, call it C, of size 4 X 4.

Assuming the matrices will *always* be upper triangular, you could reduce the number of computations required by initializing the C matrix to all 0 elements and then working through ONLY the upper triangular parts. Something like the following (assumes A, B, and C matrices are already defined and initialized):

```
double dummy;
int i, j, k;
int mRows, nCols, pCols; // Number of rows of A, and columns of B and C

for (k = 0; k < mRows; ++k) { // Do each row of A with each column of B
   for (i = 0; i < pCols; ++i) {
      dummy = 0.0;
      for (j = 0; j <= i; ++j) dummy += A_Matrix[k][j]*B_Matrix[j][i];
      C_Matrix[k][i] = dummy;
   } // End for i
} // End for k
```

If you wanted to reduce the number of computations further, and if you know the first column of the A matrix is *always* going to be 0, you could start the loops on the 1-st element instead of the 0-th element. i.e.,

```
for (k = 0; k < mRows; ++k) { // Do each row of A with each column of B
   for (i = 1; i < pCols; ++i) {
      dummy = 0.0;
      for (j = 1; j < nCols; ++j) dummy += A_Matrix[k][j]*B_Matrix[j][i];
      C_Matrix[k][i] = dummy;
   } // End for i
} // End for k
```

I think the simplest way to solve this problem is to use regular matrix notation. Trying to expand it, like you have done, just complicates it and I think you are shooting yourself in the foot.